# How to get the store code in a phtml file of Magento2?

Tags: multistore, phtml, store-view, view, store-code

In a custom phtml file I have to get the code associated to the store view (not the Id), any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $store_code    = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
```